# vim eclim slow scroll method/properties list

Tags: vim, autocomplete, eclim

I like to use eclim with vim and auto-completition function, but i have a small question. When i press ^x^u then i see the list of methods, when im scrolling it with ^n , it's scrolling slow, but if i scroll with cursor buttons (Up,Down) it scroll good fast and useful. What i need to change in scrolling ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, when you're scrolling with CTRL-N, it changes the auto complete option when you press the keys. For example, in java, I'm typing System.out, but I want the out to auto complete. I would type System.^x^u and it would scroll through the option when I pressed ^n. So, if you press ^n faster, it should scroll faster.